# Reduce matrix to a vector

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, matrix

I have the following list

```
{{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2}}, {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 3}}, {{0, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 4}}}
```

but I would like to have, simply, a list of triplets, that is

```
{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {0, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 4}}
```

In particular I am trying to use Table to generate some points in a 2D grid to ListPlod3D A 2 function. I have a function of two variables, $f(x,y)$, and I would like to compute it in discrete points in a region of the 2D plane $x$ vs $y$. To do so I need a list like $\{\{x_1,y_1,f(x_1,y_1)\},\{x_2,y_2,f(x_2,y_2)\},...\{x_n,y_n,f(x_n,y_n)\},\}$ as an input for ListPlot3D.

Comment: See [`List Manipulation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do so you can use Level. For example, in your case:

```
list={{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2}}, {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 3}}, {{0, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 4}}}

Level[list,{-2}]
```

This should give the result.

Answer (score 7):

There is a built-in function for just this called [`Catenate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catenate.html).  It can be used for this example as

```
list = {{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2}}, {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 3}}, {{0, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 4}}};
Catenate@list
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {0, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 4}}

Though. if you're just looking for the plot, you can use [`DiscretePlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot3D) to generate the plot directly with your given domain.  This way you don't even have to worry about data generation and manipulation.

Answer (score 6):

Two more ways:

```
list = {{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2}}, {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 3}}, {{0, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 4}}};

Flatten[list, 1]
(*    {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {0, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 4}}    *)

Join @@ list
(*    {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {0, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 4}}    *)
```

Comment: And `Cases[list, {__?NumericQ}, All]` or `Cases[list, _?VectorQ, All]`